# How to test amazon s3 in sandbox environment with AmazonS3Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you test S3 in a sandbox environment when your code uses an AmazonS3Client?

```
IAmazonS3 amazonS3Client =
           Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(s3AccessKey, s3SecretKey, config);

var request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
    BucketName = "bucketname",
    Key = "filename",
    ContentType = "application/json",
    ContentBody = "body"
};

amazonS3Client.PutObject(request);
```

I've tried S3Ninja and FakeS3 but the AmazonS3Client didn't hit them, which leads me to believe that an AmazonS3Client doesn't behave like a normal rest client.

The only solution I can think of is to convert the code to use a rest client and manually build the requests and headers just so that I can use S3Ninja or FakeS3.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using a mock for this.

Comment: @tedder42 I used a mock for unit testing, but I am now doing BVT testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got FakeS3 to work. My problem was that I needed to update my host file (/etc/hosts):

`127.0.0.1   myBucketName.s3.amazon.com s3.amazon.com`

The reason we have to do this is because the url to put objects to is http://bucketname.s3.amazon.com, so when running locally your dns will not understand where to go for bucketname.s3.amazon.com

Answer (score 1):

Instead of spending time & energy in getting on the S3 Mockups & Fake S3 - better approach would be to create a new S3 bucket and use it.

S3 isn't costly ( relatively ); there are several way you can optimize the cost in S3 - by setting up life-cycle rule ( delete all the objects - in a day - so today's object would be deleted at Close of today ) you keep the cost at check.

Also setup RRS - Reduced Redundant Storage for your S3 bucket - it roughly reduces the cost further by 1/3 the regular price.

Comment: This solution isn't viable for offline testing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it is relevant nowdays for you, but there is a fully functional local AWS cloud stack called [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), and it's free.